# Telnetlib Connection to Virtual Router

Tags: python, network-programming, telnetlib

Im am attempting to use the python telnetlib library to connect to a virtual router that I have installed on my machine with VMWARE pro. I am able to ping the virtual router via its G0/2 interface ip address 10.2.162.206.

When I run my script that is intended to connect to the vritual router and run the "show users" command I get nothing back and then terminates the connection after a few minutes.

```
import getpass
import telnetlib

HOST = "10.2.162.206"
user = 'Cisco1'
password = 'class1'

def show_users_telnet():
    '''Return logged in users'''

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

    tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

    tn.read_until(b'#')
    tn.write(b'show users\n')

    stdout = tn.read_until(b'#').decode('utf-8')
    print(stdout)

show_users_telnet()
```

I am also attaching a screenshot of the virtual routers interfaces which I can ping.

[image: Virtual Router]

This is the output from vscode

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\OneDrive - xxxx xxx\Documents\Universidad\AdmindeRedes\telnet-1.py", line 25, in 
show_users_telnet()
File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\OneDrive - xxxx xxx\Documents\Universidad\AdmindeRedes\telnet-1.py", line 19, in show_users_telnet
3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\telnetlib.py", line 315, in read_until
if selector.select(timeout):  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\selectors.py", line 324, in select    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\selectors.py", line 315, in _select    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt